# Resizing window causing misalignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my web pages using HTML5 , JavaScript, Jquery, and CSS3!
It's just the way i need it to be when the window is full screen.
Just as I resize the window, the alignment goes haywire!
I need a simple fix!Please help! Thanks in advance!
Here is a small part of my code:

```
    <img id="myimage1" onclick="changeimage1()"  src="images/build_i.png"  />
    <img id="myimage2" onclick="changeimage2()"  src="images/apply_i.png"  />
    <img id="myimage3" onclick="changeimage3()"  src="images/learn_i.png"  />
```

If i resize this window to the minimum the alignment changes.It starts to come one below the other.How do i get rid of that?

Comment: Great description. Where's the code?

Comment: So, this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Give  `min-width` and `min-height` to body tag/parent element. (*In CSS*)

**or**

Try this: (*In jQuery*)

```
$(window).on('ready resize',function(){
    // post your code here related to layouts
});
```